# Как сделать, чтобы приложение запоминало действия в аккаунте?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пишу приложение в котором можно будет просматривать например свои фото, музыку и т.д

```
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Loginform where username='" + metroTextBox1.Text + "' and password='" + metroTextBox2.Text + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
        if (i == 0)
        {
            //conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели неверный логин или пароль");

        }
        else
        {

            this.Hide();
            LENTA f = new LENTA();
            f.Show();
        }
```

А это регистрация:

```
if (username.Text == "" || pass.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("please fill all fields");
        else if (pass.Text != conpass.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("password do not match");
        else
        {
            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UserAdd", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", metroTextBox3.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Firstname", name.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", surname.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telnumber", tel.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", pass.Text.Trim());

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("registration is successfull");
                Clear();
            }
        }
```

У меня вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы приложение запоминало действия в аккаунте?

Comment: Куда не-будь может записывать эти данные? Например в базу данных, или же в файл! :)

Comment: Да, все данные от аккаунта автоматически записываются в БД Microsoft SQL Server в таблицу

Comment: `запоминало действия в аккаунте` - что вы под этим имеете ввиду?

Comment: нуу сохраненные тексты в TextBox например для начала например захожу под именем Анатолий пишу в текстбокс Анатолий а после того как я вышел и снова зашел то тот же текст оставался бы и так же с другими аккаунтами

Comment: Когда вы отвечаете кому-то в комментариях - пишите его ник (если обращаетесь ко мне, то так @tym32167) иначе я не получу уведомления о вашем сообщении. Когда я к вам обращаюсь, я этого могу не делать, так как пишу под вашим вопросом и вы только по этому уже получите уведомление автоматом

Comment: чтобы сохранять данные и потом их использовать вам нужна БД. БД у вас уже есть, добавлять данные вы туда умеете (вы же написали регистрацию), получать данные тоже умеете (вы же написали логин для юзера), потому не вижу у вас конкретной проблемы - надо вам что то сохранить в БД - сохраняйте.

Comment: @tym32167 СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> в котором можно будет просматривать например свои
>   фото, музыку и т.д

Для запоминания фото и музыки вам нужна будет не база данных, а сохранение их в папку проекта. 
Пример для сохранения фото с помощью класса `SaveFileDialog`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
   // Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the Image  
   // assigned to Button2.  
   SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();  
   saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";  
   saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";  
   saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();  

   // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.  
   if(saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")  
   {  
      // Saves the Image via a FileStream created by the OpenFile method.  
      System.IO.FileStream fs =   
         (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();  
      // Saves the Image in the appropriate ImageFormat based upon the  
      // File type selected in the dialog box.  
      // NOTE that the FilterIndex property is one-based.  
      switch(saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)  
      {  
         case 1 :   
         this.button2.Image.Save(fs,   
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
         break;  

         case 2 :   
         this.button2.Image.Save(fs,   
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);  
         break;  

         case 3 :   
         this.button2.Image.Save(fs,   
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);  
         break;  
      }  

   fs.Close();  
   }  
}
```

Ну и музыку таким же способом сохранять.

> а после того как я вышел и снова зашел то тот же текст оставался бы и
>   так же с другими аккаунтами

Ну а для этого либо сохранять кучу текстовых файлов(по файлу на пользователя), либо базу(см. [winforms сохранение в базу данных](https://www.google.com/search?q=winforms%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85&oq=winforms%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85&aqs=chrome..69i57.651j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) в Google).